# Issue with replacing css/html code with wp hook

Tags: php, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I have issue to replace some html content.
On WP admin plugin page side I want to apply like this code in plugin default .php (like function.php):

```
function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
jQuery(function($){
$('.nameofclass').html('<p>test</p>');
});
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');
```

I test only`<script></script>` on fronted site and works ok, but I want to display some changes in specific css in wp admin dashboard on some plugin page, but that not work good with above wp hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `admin_head` hooks.

```
function wpb_admin_hook_javascript() {
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.nameofclass').html('<p>test</p>');
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('admin_head', 'wpb_admin_hook_javascript');
```

Comment: Thank you for code, Is possible to set that `<script></script>` to run in specific wp plugin page in wp admin?

Comment: Yes, can you share the plugin page link? how did you make that page? using which function?

Comment: That is standard page in wp admin /wp-admin/admin.php?page=someplugin

Comment: Try this [get_current_screen()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/)